# multiple query from duplicated form

Tags: php, mysqli

I have form like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="search" name="nip" action="search.php" method="post">
    <button>Szukaj</button>
</form>
```

and to search "nip" in database i use sql like this:

```
$query = "SELECT komun, 
               problema, 
               termin, 
               blaclist, 
               scored
        FROM scoring 
        WHERE  `nip` = '$nip'";
```

but i have no idea how to do it when i make form like this to pritnt more than one thing from database with search criteria

```
<form>
    <input type="search" name="nip" action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="nip" action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="nip" action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="nip" action="search.php" method="post">
    <button>Szukaj</button>
</form>
```

i print it on webpage like this:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
    if ($result)
    {
        // it return number of rows in the table.
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          
           if ($row == 0)
            {
                echo "Przewoznik nie byl oceniany<BR>";  
            }

           if ($row != 0)
            {
                
                $row_data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                
                $avg_komunikacja = $row_data[0] / $row_data[4]; 
                $avg_problematycznosc = $row_data[1] / $row_data[4];
                $avg_terminowosc = $row_data[2] / $row_data[4];
                
                $avg_all = (($avg_komunikacja + $avg_problematycznosc + $avg_terminowosc) / 3);
```

I have no idea how get that data from database and print it

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Use wither `name="nip[]"` to make an array of inputs called `nip` or give them unique names

Comment: i have no idea how get that data from database and print it

Comment: So now is the time you have to hit books and the tutorials

Comment: you are right, anyway thank for help i will go fight with that arrays